# How to add watch to an element out of Angular controller context

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add listener to the input field. The HTML has Angular JS code and is client controlled. They use our JS file and I need to monitor (and do some action) when typed in to input field.

I tried to add watch using `$scope.$watch` but that works only when I add it in clients implementation:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window, $timeout) { }
```

But I don't want my client to know that I am adding watch on the input field which makes me add the above code into my JS as well.

This makes the initialization of controller on clients JS file fail to load. How can add watch or listener on input field?

Comment: you can have `<input ng-model="value" ng-change="action(value)"/>` which will call your _action_ function, where you can do something with the value from the input filed. Either way you need a controller

Comment: and the controller is initiated in clients js and i don't have control of changing it. How else can i achieve it?

Comment: do you just need a **keylogger**? you can do this: `document.onkeydown = (e)=>{ e=e || window.event; console.log(e); }`

Comment: Great, that works perfect with key input. I want to restrict that onkeydown to specific input field only? Also, the event get triggers when i use ctrl/alt buttons.

Comment: your input: `<input id="t" oninput="foo()">`, separate script: `<script> foo = (e)=>{ x = document.getElementById("t").value; console.log(x); } </script>`

Comment: without `oninput` (hidden): `<input id="t">` and `<script> document.getElementById("t").addEventListener("input", foo);  function foo(e){ console.log(e); } </script>`

Comment: the input field is controlled by client side, all i would know is the id of the element. I don't want to add any oninput methods dynamically to the field as they might already have one.

Comment: Thanks a ton for such quick responses. The addevent listener is not working as expected because of angularjs on input field. but i managed to get the result to some extent by using document.oninput = (e)=>{ e=e || window.event; if(e.data !== null && e.srcElement.id === "some_id") { console.log(e.data); }} I need to figure out a way to do something when text is pasted into the field.

Comment: note that the use of keyloggers (without user's consent) might be illegal